# How to make the Alert / Modal / Dialog service appear when the application is closed react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, service, background-task

I have a problem, here I made two applications say, seller and buyer. When the buyer pays with the hit API / Socket IO the Seller application displays a popup. These Pop-Up are like phone calls or video calls.

[image: #]

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Actually I want to ask for the implementation fundamentals first, if I have a dummy project where when using intervals pop up when the application is killed.

Comment: You can use setInterval() with callback that open popup on specific condition. you can follow below npm library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-dialog

Comment: Yeah, I can Use Modal, Alert and even toast, but the problem here is outside the app or app in the state of being killed. such as Whatsapp even if you do not open WhatsApp if there is an incoming call it will pop up immediately.

Comment: You want to receives notification and display a ringing UI(even when the app is killed and phone is locked) ?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204030/discussion-between-ravi-sharma-and-zidniryi).

Comment: I also wants to implement same thing in my react native app. There is video calling functionality in my app and i want show incoming call alert to the user when app is in kill state or lock state. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @RaviSharma I have same issue, can I chat with you about the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved you must use System Alert Window for floating or you can use Buble in android Q and higher.

```
https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-system-alert-window-deprecate-bubbles/
```

You should use a bridge to your native Java to your React Native Component.

Comment: can you please tell me how did you solved it for react native

Comment: Im bridge the java native to react native code.

Comment: can you please give me code example

Comment: @mdkamrul its bit private code, and Im not longer work at my company but I still should keep the code secret.

But the big picture logic is: use create your own service win window location permission in android and then triger with FCM .

Comment: Here some reference @mdkamrul https://mobilityquotient.com/article/creating-a-native-bridge-in-react-native#:~:text=%20Creating%20a%20Native%20Bridge%20in%20React%20Native,JavaScript%20file%20for%20Native%20level%20interactions%20More%20